# How do I overlay two .fits images each with different WCS / resolutions?

Tags: python, imshow, astronomy, astropy, fits

I'm trying to plot contours from one image of an object, let's say in band A, on top of a lower resolution image of that same object, let's say in band Z.

Both images are in large fits files, so I have to create a 2D cutout of each. However, the image in band Z has far fewer pixels than that of band A. So, when I try to plot them in the same figure, the image from band Z plots according to pixel dimensions and is therefore very tiny in the bottom left corner of the figure (see plot in link below). I need both images to plot on the basis of astronomical angular dimensions, not pixels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.nddata import Cutout2D
from reproject import reproject_interp

# Read in .fits images and WCS information
image_a = fits.open("image_a.fits")
image_z = fits.open("image_z.fits")
wcs_a = WCS(image_a.header).celestial
wcs_z = WCS(image_z.header).celestial

# Define object RA and DEC
obj_coords = SkyCoord(ra=135.19081*u.degree, dec=0.68991393*u.degree, frame='fk5')

# Create 2D cutouts of the object in each band in a 6 by 6 arcsec box
size = u.Quantity((6, 6), u.arcsec)
stamp_a = Cutout2D(image_a.data, obj_coords, size, wcs=wcs_a)
stamp_z = Cutout2D(image_z.data, obj_coords, size, wcs=wcs_z)

# Plot the the stamp in band Z with contours from band A
ax = plt.subplot(projection = wcs_z)
plt.imshow(stamp_z.data, cmap='gray', origin='lower', alpha=1)
ax.contour(stamp_a.data, levels = [2*sigma,3*sigma,4*sigma,5*sigma], 
colors='green')
```

[Resulting plot (click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNiMl.png)

I've also seen something about using reproject. I tried it but don't think I totally understand it as it just results in a tiny little pixel. This is what I tried:

```
array, footprint = reproject_interp((stamp_a.data, wcs_a), image_z.header)
plt.imshow(array, origin='lower')
```

Let me know if there is any info I'm missing to answer the question. I've just made the switch to python last week after using IDL for a few years, so I apologize if it's a bit rough.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with how you use [reproject](http://reproject.readthedocs.io/) is that you pass `(stamp_a.data, wcs_a)`, but `wcs_a` is the WCS from the original image, not from the stamp.

You can get a WCS object that matches your stamp from the [Cutout2D](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.utils.Cutout2D.html) image. I think changing to `(stamp_a.data, stamp_a.wcs)` will give you a correct result.

Have you had a look at [astropy.visualisation.wcsaxes](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/index.html) yet? You can see an example [here](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/overlays.html#contours) how to plot an image, and overplot contours from a second image with a different WCS. If this works for you, it will be simpler than using `Cutout2D` and `reproject` manually.

I'm not sure concerning performance; if your images are huge you still might want to do the cutouts like you do now. If memory / execution time isn't a problem, you can just plot the whole image and then set the range you want with `wcsaxes` (see their tutorial docs).

The question whether to do the reproject yourself or let `matplotlib` and `astropy.visualisation.wcsaxes` behind the scenes is also a matter of taste. Using `reproject` directly is a bit more code and more complex, but will give you more control over the exact reprojection method used (e.g. interpolation or the slower flux-conserving `reproject_exact`) and might be easier to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks so much @Christoph! I combined some of your recommendations to make it work. I plotted the stamp from the image with fewer pixels projecting the stamp's WCS onto the plot, then set the autoscale on 'False', and overplotted the contours from the other image using that image's WCS. A huge part of this not working originally was me using the wrong WCS objects throughout (stamp vs. original image). Thanks again!